# Is this possible with sql?

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES(something_from_another_table, value);
```

With `something_from_another_table` being a SQL command? Like, is there something I can do that's equivelant to:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES((SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE id = 3), value);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) 
SELECT value1, 'value2' FROM table2 WHERE id = 3
```

Where value1 is the value from the 'other table' and value2 is a constant that you've included in that select statement.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) 
SELECT table2.value1, value2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

take a look especially in the examples.

I would recommend reading full syntax of [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html), [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) and [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) SQL commands to begin with. Then expand to [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html) and [DDL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html).

Go slowly and work out examples.

Answer (score 0):

You definately can. It should work similar as the example below;

```
INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
(SELECT store_name, Sales, Date FROM Sales_Information WHERE Year(Date) = 2010)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you specify the keyword "Values" on the insert statement you are trying to insert just a value. the current way to do that is assigning the value of the "something_from_another_table" into a variable and then, make your insert

```
DECLARE @ANYVALUE AS VARCHAR(40)
SELECT @ANYVALUE = ANYFIELD FROM table2 WHERE id = 3
INSERT INTO table1 (FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES(@ANYVALUE, VALUE2)
```

On this way always will insert one record. the other correct way will insert n record as the where statement can filter.

```
INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
(SELECT store_name, Sales, Date FROM Sales_Information WHERE Year(Date) = 2010)
```